# How to get a list of date time objects in python and find out the minimum

Tags: python, datetime

I need to find the minimum date out of a list of date time objects in python. However creation of the list throws a syntax error in Python shell.

`l = [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 18, 13, 45, 2, tzinfo=<UTC>),datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 18, 3, 45, 2, tzinfo=<UTC>)]`

The above gives a

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
    l = [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 18, 13, 45, 2, tzinfo=<UTC>),datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 18, 3, 45, 2, tzinfo=<UTC>)]
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax .
```

How do I overcome that and get the minimum out of the list.

Comment: could you comment here the exact error code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a syntax error because you're pasting in `<UTC>` which isn't legal Python, it's just the `__repr__` method on a timezone object. Use a timezone library like `pytz` if the timezones  are significant to you, otherwise just drop them.

Past that, you can call `min` on anything that implements `__lt__`, which `datetime` does. Just call `min` on the list of datetimes, and it'll work.

Answer (score 3):

I think this would help

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: import pytz

In [3]: l = [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 18, 13, 45, 2, tzinfo=pytz.UTC),datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 18, 3, 45, 2, tzinfo=pytz.UTC)]

In [4]: min(l)
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 18, 3, 45, 2, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```